# How to display content of txt file?(with the ability to edit)

Tags: php, file-io

How to display content of txt file?

I store file in database. I need display their content on website(something like form field?). I need to be able to edit it. This is example path to file:

> src_files/out_11.txt

I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: You should use `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents();` functions. These are basic I/O operations that can be easily find on Internet. Do some research before asking questions.

Comment: i second that, or add some information to your question ,as its not very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you read the file to variable, then fill  with value of this variable, and then on form submit update DB value with one from textarea. 
Though, you have to watch encoding changes or text can be screwed.

For exact functions, as it is PHP, you can look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ , it has nice search, examples, and is totally user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing a file in a database, you mean it's contents? To edit the text just put it inside a textarea tag; if it's in a file you can do

```
<textarea> <? readfile("src_files/ut_11.txt") ?> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is pretty easy actually

First grab the content with `fopen`, [nice tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileread.php), or `readfile`

Place the content in a textarea so that the user can edit it.

Then when the user submits it you can use `fopen` again to [save the file](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php) or use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)